# iPhone - which will produce the most efficient/smaller code?

Tags: objective-c

Which one of these will produce the most efficient/smaller binary code?

**THIS**

```
int sum = 0;
for (NSNumber * oneObj in objArray) {
    if ([oneObj intValue] > 10)
        sum += [oneObj intValue];
    else
        sum -= [oneObj intValue];
}
```

**OR THIS?**

```
int sum = 0;
for (NSNumber * oneObj in objArray) {
    sum += ([oneObj intValue] > 10) ? oneObj : -oneObj;
}
```

does it make any difference writing the IF in this condensed form?

Comment: The compiler will probably optimize it anyway, so I'm guessing both will be the same.

Comment: I am very interested in this as well. Hopefully the person who answers gives details!

Comment: Smells like premature optimization to me.

Comment: I doubt that the optimisations will be worth the effort. What will matter more is readability and maintainability. In this case the first one is much better, although I'd always use `{}`s around if and else statements for consistency.

Comment: This is purely for the convenience of the programmer. Both compile into exactly the same binary code....

Comment: @MattBall - what do you mean?

Comment: You can look at the assembler output in Xcode pretty easily. Menu: Product>Generate Output>Generate Assembly File. Your code is invalid, BTW; you need to either do `sum += [oneObj intValue];` or store the `intValue` in a temp variable. You can't do primitive arithmetic with an `NSNumber` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled versions will be identical.

It's two different ways of expressing the same thing

Comment: And yes, reeks to high heaven of premature optimization

Comment: I don't disagree _per se_, I just like to see supporting evidence.